Hi , Need support to decompose Mongo DB dump - > Then re-construct that again
I am taking Mongo DB Dump from a production server where we have some limitation on file size which can be transferred from production to local environment.
So we are planning to 1)Take Mongo DB Dump in production 2)Decompose that huge dump into multiple pieces 3)Shift all the pieces to local setup 4)Then re-join all the pieces
Need suggestions - if this process will work fine or there are other ways of doing this activity Please support with relevant commands in linux.
Thanks

There is no need to save the dump into a file. You can pipe the output directly into import tool, for example like this:
mongodump --uri="mongodb://production-server:27017" --db=some_database --collection=some_collection --archive=- | mongorestore --uri="mongodb://local-server:27017" --nsFrom="some_database.some_collection" --nsTo="some_or_other_database.some_or_other_collection" --archive=-

You can do the same with mongoexport ... | mongoimport ...
